# Symfony 4 roles management

Tags: authentication, symfony4, user-roles

I am currently working on a project in Symfony 4 a website for a library.
While configuring roles in the file security.yaml, I decommented this line :

```
access_control:
      { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
      { path: ^/profil, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

And than I have this error :

[image_error_roles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7pc3.png)

My User class :

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use App\Repository\UtilisateurRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=UtilisateurRepository::class)
 * @UniqueEntity(
 * fields={"Email"},
 * message="L'email que vous avez indiqué est déjà utilisé !" 
 * )
 */
class Utilisateur implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $Nom;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $Prenom;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\Email()
     */
    private $Email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $Adresse;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
    */
    private $Mdp;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $Username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\Length(min="8", minMessage="Votre mot de passe doit faire minimum 8 caractères")
     * @Assert\EqualTo(propertyPath="Confirm_Password",message="Votre mot de passe doit être pareil")
     */
    private $Password;

    /*
    * @Assert\EqualTo(propertyPath="Password",message="Votre mot de passe doit être pareil")
    */
    public $Confirm_Password;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=TypeUtilisateur::class, inversedBy="utilisateur")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $typeUtilisateur;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="json")
     */
    private $roles = [];

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getNom(): ?string
    {
        return $this->Nom;
    }

    public function setNom(string $Nom): self
    {
        $this->Nom = $Nom;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPrenom(): ?string
    {
        return $this->Prenom;
    }

    public function setPrenom(string $Prenom): self
    {
        $this->Prenom = $Prenom;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->Email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $Email): self
    {
        $this->Email = $Email;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAdresse(): ?string
    {
        return $this->Adresse;
    }

    public function setAdresse(string $Adresse): self
    {
        $this->Adresse = $Adresse;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getMdp(): ?string
    {
        return $this->Mdp;
    }

    public function setMdp(string $Mdp): self
    {
        $this->Mdp = $Mdp;

        return $this;
    }

    public function eraseCredentials(){}

    public function getsalt(){}

    public function getUsername(): ?string
    {
        return $this->Username;
    }

    public function setUsername(string $Username): self
    {
        $this->Username = $Username;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPassword(): ?string
    {
        return $this->Password;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $Password): self
    {
        $this->Password = $Password;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTypeUtilisateur(): ?TypeUtilisateur
    {
        return $this->typeUtilisateur;
    }

    public function setTypeUtilisateur(?TypeUtilisateur $typeUtilisateur): self
    {
        $this->typeUtilisateur = $typeUtilisateur;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getRoles()
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;
        $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';

        return array_unique($roles);

    }

    public function setRoles(array $roles): self
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;

        return $this;
    }

    
}
```

File security.yaml :

```
security:
  encoders:
    App\Entity\Utilisateur:
      algorithm: bcrypt
  # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
  providers:
    users_in_memory: { memory: null }
    in_database:
      entity:
        class: App\Entity\Utilisateur
        property: Email
  firewalls:
    dev:
      pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
      security: false
    main:
      anonymous: true
      lazy: true

      provider: in_database

      form_login:
        login_path: security_login
        check_path: security_login

      logout:
        path: security_logout
        target: home

      # activate different ways to authenticate
      # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#firewalls-authentication

      # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
      # switch_user: true

  # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
  # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
  access_control:
      { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
      { path: ^/profil, roles: ROLE_USER }
  
  # role_hierarchy:
     ROLE_LIBRAIRE: ROLE_USER
     ROLE_ADMIN: ROLE_LIBRAIRE
```

I don't know what is the problem, thanks for you help !

Comment: What if you uncomment `# role_hierarchy:` ?

Answer (score 0):

The error message says clearly there is a problem with your yaml.

```yaml
  access_control:
      { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
      { path: ^/profil, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

should be:

```yaml
  access_control:
      - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
      - { path: ^/profil, roles: ROLE_USER }
```